# Ignoring "-" in Tcl

Tags: tcl

I'm writing a code to do sth when it detects "-" in a string . when i do :

```
switch [string index $code $j] {
    "-" { set mem($ptr) [expr $mem($ptr) - 1] ; }
```

But Tcl interprets this as it's "-" as a `switch` option prefix :

```
bad option "-": must be -exact, -glob, -regexp, -command procname or --
```

I tried to replace "-" with another character :

```
regsub -all "-" $code "m" code
```

But it's the same :

```
bad switch "-": must be -all, -nocase, -expanded, -line, -linestop, -lineanchor, -start, or --
```

It even happens when I use `\u2d` :

```
regsub -all \u2d $code "m" code
switch $code \u2d {puts "hi" ;}
```

Comment: Tip of the day: instead of `set mem($ptr) [expr $mem($ptr) - 1]`, use `incr mem($ptr) -1`. If you don't, at least brace the expression: `expr {$mem($ptr) - 1}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a known problem, and to solve that the special option `--` was introduced. It means end of switches, meaning after `--` there will be no other switches, treat the next token as data...

So your code will work if you just use

```
switch -- [string index $code $j] {
    "-" {set mem($ptr) [expr $mem($ptr) - 1]}
}
```

Comment: The other fix is to upgrade to 8.6, where if there are just two arguments to `switch` it _never_ treats either as an option (because that was always a deeply vexing thing to do in the first place).